# Setting custom property in msi file

Tags: windows-installer

How to set custom property in a msi file on the fly? I do not want to pass the custom property using msiexec. I want to save the value of the property in the msi file itself based on user log in.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't get. I guess you are using some tool to create msi (wix?) and want to know how to set a custom property, right?

Answer (score 1):

See the [USERNAME property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372385(VS.85).aspx). The only options for setting a property are: at authoring time; at the command line (directly or in a transform); and in a custom action. However the information you want may be in one of the properties set by the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following piece of code (after you download the WindosInstaller class written by Ian Schoen Mahr Mariano

from here

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/msiinterop/msiinterop.zip

```
    public static bool ChangeProperty(string MsiPath, string property, string value)
    {
        bool result = true;
        IntPtr view = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr dataBase = IntPtr.Zero;
        MsiError err;

        try
        {
            err = MsiInterop.MsiOpenDatabase(MsiPath, MsiDbPersistMode.Transact, out dataBase);
            if (err == MsiError.Success)
            {
                string sql = "INSERT INTO Property (Property, Value) VALUES ('" + property + "', '" + value + "')";
                err = MsiInterop.MsiDatabaseOpenView(dataBase, sql, out view);

                err = MsiInterop.MsiViewExecute(view, IntPtr.Zero);
                if (err == MsiError.FunctionFailed)
                {
                    string sqlUpdate = @"UPDATE Property SET Value = '" + value + "' WHERE Property = '" + property + "'";
                    err = MsiInterop.MsiDatabaseOpenView(dataBase, sqlUpdate, out view);
                    err = MsiInterop.MsiViewExecute(view, IntPtr.Zero);
                }
            }
            err = MsiInterop.MsiDatabaseCommit(dataBase);
        }
        catch
        {
            result = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            err = MsiInterop.MsiViewClose(view);
            err = MsiInterop.MsiCloseHandle(dataBase);
        }
        return result;
    }
```